# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'

Tags: python, django

New to django, I am trying to understand this error.
The forms is in the folder of the project.
My forms.py is importing from django forms.

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form): 
email = forms.EmailField(label='Courriel')
password = forms.CharField(label='Mot de passe',
                        widget = forms.PasswordInput)
```

My views.py is importing LoginForm

I don't know why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: How are you importing `LoginForm` in `views.py`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like it should be working, you might want to post the full error and more of your code. Something like this should be working

```
# forms.py
from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form): 
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Courriel')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Mot de passe',
                        widget = forms.PasswordInput)
```

and the views

```
# views.py
from forms import LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render


def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            # do something when valid
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': login_form})
```

where you have a folder structure like

```
/app/
   forms.py
   views.py
```

Answer (score 11):

You're probably importing `LoginForm` in views.py as following:

```
from forms import LoginForm
```

Change that to

```
from .forms import LoginForm
```

Comment: This actually worked for me in Flask !